# Titles getting cut off in mobile app built with kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an open source project and I am kind of stumped. Whenever the titles are being displayed in another language the titles begin to be cut off as you can see in the attached picture. Has anyone experience similar problems, and how would.you fix it?

[you can see how some items are getting cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bALGC.jpg)

Comment: there is some type of view maybe TextView so set its height to WRAP_CONTENT

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is the size of the text, whenever it's too big the view get messed up. Maybe you can limit the text to two lines if you are able too and use ellipsize to add the dots at the end.